# torchvision.transforms.Normalize() slows down learning when adding to torchvision,transforms.Compose()

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

when i use

```
train_transforms = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
  torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(), 
  torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
])
```

for loading MNIST dataset, it slows down learning even with `mean = 0` and `std = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformations are performed on CPU, and it doesn't matter if the mean/std are all zeros (BTW, don't set std to 0). To speed up the transform you have two options:

1. If you don't have any data augmentations in your flow, just transform the data and save it as normalized tensors (pickled or something).
2. You can also use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` with some arguments: for example `num_workers` specifies how many CPU processes to use to transform the data. THere is also `pin_memory` which will speed up the whole thing if you are using CUDA.

Comment: I use CUDA, but the problem is that when do not use Normalize() it learns much faster.  
```pin_memory``` doesn't help

Comment: What do you mean by "learns faster" -- do you mean it "converges in less number of epochs" or "less time per epoch". If the first one, it's a little odd, as normalization generally speeds up the convergence. If the latter, use the steps described above